# Backbone.js onModelEvent

Tags: backbone.js

When you look into the source code of Backbone.js, version 0.9.2, there is

"_onModelEvent":

This method is responsible of forwarding events from the model to the collection (bubbling up).

So when you change something in a model which is part of a collection (with "set"), there is a change event, and because (in the add method) the _onModelEvent method was bound to the model ("all"), this method gets called.

I also see, that there is a destroy method, which triggers a "destroy" event.

But why does the author (in the first line of the _onModelEvent) check, if the event name is "add" or "remove". Normally there is no "add" event on the model?

I do not understand this.

Can somebody explain it to me?

Thanks in advance

```
_onModelEvent: function(event, model, collection, options) {
  if ((event == 'add' || event == 'remove') && collection != this) return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Backbone you can create [nested model structures and collections](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested). So you can create a collection where the model is a collection. That is way the check in place:

So from the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):

> _onModelEvent:
>
> Internal method called every time a model in the set fires an event.
>   Sets need to update their indexes when models change ids. All other
>   events simply proxy through. "add" and "remove" events that originate
>   in other collections are ignored.

So if you have a collection as a model. It won't delegate the `add` or `remove` event if items were added/removed to/from the child collections because in that case only the child collection is changed and not the parent.